# shell commands not working within SFTP script

Tags: shell, sftp

I am a novice in programming.. I have this sftp script where it sftp to the other server check some conditions & then get the file.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

while read line
do
#echo $line
if [[ $line =~ ^#  ]];
then
#echo $line;
continue;

else
serverIP=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f1`
userID=`echo $line|cut -d',' -f2`
fi
done < sftp.conf

cd /root

sshpass -p red32hat sftp $userID@$serverIP <<EOF
for (; ;) 
do
cd /root/perl
#foreach my $file (<$inputdir/*seq>) {
for $file in *seq 
do
abc1=`find $file -mmin +1`;
if [[ $abc1 eq "" ]] 
then
echo "Skipping file as of now as file is not completed \n";
continue;
fi
mget $file
done
sleep 30
done
bye
EOF
```

but it is throwing error at every sftp step saying "invalid command".. I guess general shell commands are not working within sftp... please help...below is the error message...

```
eankuls@L9AHR43:~/Idea_Expan$ bash -x sftp_idea.sh
+ read line
+ [[ #bsackjsabckjdsbcds =~ ^# ]]
+ continue
+ read line
+ [[ rinacac-test,root =~ ^# ]]
++ echo rinacac-test,root
++ cut -d, -f1
+ serverIP=rinacac-test
++ echo rinacac-test,root
++ cut -d, -f2
+ userID=root
+ read line
+ [[ #geet =~ ^# ]]
+ continue
+ read line
+ sshpass -p red32hat sftp root@rinacac-test

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    These computer resources, specifically Internet access and E-mail, are
    provided for authorized users only. 

    IF YOU ARE NOT AN AUTHORIZED USER, PLEASE EXIT IMMEDIATELY.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected to rinacac-test.
sftp> for ((;;)) 
Invalid command.
sftp> do
Invalid command.
sftp> cd /root/perl
sftp> #foreach my $file (<$inputdir/*seq>) {
sftp> for file in *seq 
Invalid command.
sftp> do
Invalid command.
sftp> abc1=`find $file -mmin +1`;
Invalid command.
sftp> if [[ $abc1 == "" ]]
Invalid command.
sftp> then
Invalid command.
sftp> echo "Skipping file as of now as file is not completed \n";
Invalid command.
sftp> continue;
Invalid command.
sftp> fi
Invalid command.
sftp> mget $file
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
File "/root/perl/$file" not found.
sftp> done
Invalid command.
sftp> sleep 30
Invalid command.
sftp> done
Invalid command.
sftp> bye
```

Comment: i guess you do not have sftp installed . please install using sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Comment: Hi...I have got sftp installed on my system.. if i only use mget command its working fine.. I guess problem is with those other commands I am using within sftp...thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a quote to EOF to prevent expansions in the here document:

```
sshpass -p red32hat sftp "$userID@$serverIP" <<'EOF'
```

And place variables around quotes to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

Also `for $file in *seq` should be `for file in *seq`.

`for (; ;)` should also be `for ((;;))`.

`eq` in `[[ $abc1 eq "" ]]` is not a valid operator. Perhaps your mean `=` or `==`.

Comment: hi... I tried this...but for each command within here doc. it throwing "invalid command"... like: sftp> then; Invalid command..Thanks

Comment: You should provide more detail (by editing your post) how these problems occur. Try to run `bash -x your_script.sh` and show all messages on your post (not as a comment here).

Comment: hi.. I have included the error code in the post.. again -x is not working within the sftp...thanks...

Comment: @Geetika Well that was quite obvious that I haven't noticed. You're passing shellsript commands to sftp so naturally it would show an error as those commands are not valid to it. I'm not knowledgeable when it comes to ftp or sftp. Best thing you can do is refer to a valid documentation about its commands and fix your codes based from it. Best thing I could help is fix shell syntax.